# NameError in RegistrationsController#create using devise login

Tags: devise

I have a project in which I am using omniauth for Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn.  It is also using the Devise login gem.  When a user goes to the sign-up page to create a login and inputs the e-mail and selects a password, the error page `NameError in RegistrationsController#create` shows up.

This appears in the terminal:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-25 14:42:30 -0400
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MMYGtL6b6AyEuWIWwpxMg7qn8TWGXinMZTQ2K0GDsyU=", "user"=>{"email"=>"Phil9767@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'phil9767@yahoo.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 91ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x00000106162ef0>):
  activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:206:in `method_missing'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:88:in `confirmed?'
  devise (3.2.4) lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:163:in `confirmation_required?'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:142:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:142:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:142:in `each'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:142:in `all?'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:142:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `create_record'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create_record'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/TheMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/TheMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/TheMac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/TheMac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/TheMac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/TheMac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (10.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/TheMac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (28.6ms)
```

I have done many searches on stackoverflow, and it doesn't appear to be whether authentications is pluralized in the associations, nor does it seem to be related to skipping the authentication in devise.  I created a registrations controller, but it didn't seem to help.  Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Here is my user model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications

  TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX = 'change@me'
  TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX = /\Achange@me/

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  validates_format_of :email, :without => TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX, on: :update

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)

    # Get the identity and user if they exist
    identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

    # If a signed_in_resource is provided it always overrides the existing user
    # to prevent the identity being locked with accidentally created accounts.
    # Note that this may leave zombie accounts (with no associated identity) which
    # can be cleaned up at a later date.
    user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

    # Create the user if needed
    if user.nil?

      # Get the existing user by email if the provider gives us a verified email.
      # If no verified email was provided we assign a temporary email and ask the
      # user to verify it on the next step via UsersController.finish_signup
      email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
      email = auth.info.email if email_is_verified
      user = User.where(:email => email).first if email

      # Create the user if it's a new registration
      if user.nil?
        user = User.new(
          name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
          #username: auth.info.nickname || auth.uid,
          email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
          password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        )
        user.skip_confirmation!
        user.save!
      end
    end

    # Associate the identity with the user if needed
    if identity.user != user
      identity.user = user
      identity.save!
    end
    user
  end


  def email_verified?
    self.email && self.email !~ TEMP_EMAIL_REGEX
  end
end
```

This is my schema.rb

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140724042203) do

  create_table "identities", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "identities", ["user_id"], name: "index_identities_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: do you have `:confirmable` set in your User model in the list of devise modules?

Comment: Yes, it is in my user model.  I'll post it in a moment

Comment: And you ran the migrations for devise, and that column is in your schema?

Comment: To clean up your code block in your post, make sure it's all indented at least 4 spaces. You can highlight the whole section and click the `{}` button in the edit window to indent it for you.

Comment: When I tried to run the migrations for Devise I got the error 'ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError' and I had to run rake db:rollback.  I have the following in my schema.rb

Comment: You need to run the migrations to get those columns in. If it won't let you run `rake db:migrate`, run `rake db:migrate:status` to see if there are any other unrun migrations farther back that you may need to either re-run or delete. If that doesn't work, then you just need to reset your db and rerun all your migrations (which will cause any data in the db to be lost).

Answer (score 0):

Your model Users is missing the "confirmed_at" attribute.

you can create it with a new migration:

```
rails g migration add_unconfirmed_to_devise
```

and put in:

```
    class AddUnconfirmedToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t|
    #t.string   :confirmation_token
    #t.datetime :confirmed_at
    #t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
    #t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
    #t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
    #t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
    #t.datetime :locked_at
    end
  end
end
```

Just uncomment each attribute you need.